# jQuery: generating html

Tags: jquery, html

Is there a better way to do the following?

```
var html;
var i;
for (i=0; i < 4; i++) {
    html += '<div class="row">';
    html += '<span class="label">Dining Style:</span>';
    html += '<span class="control">';

    var j;
    for (j=0; j < 3; j++){
        html += '<div class="attribBox">';
            html += '<ul>';
                html += '<li><input type="checkbox" /> item 1</li>';
            html += '</ul>';
        html += '</div>';
    }
    html += '</span>';
    html += '<div class="clear"></div>';
}

$("#content").html(html);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look here

http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/

and an overview

http://www.borismoore.com/2010/10/jquery-templates-is-now-official-jquery.html

Comment: Extremely interesting. This is going to take me a bit of time to investigate, but I can see how powerful this could be!

Comment: I'm trying to understand how this works... is it possible to have templates within templates?

Comment: I believe it is possible to nest templates yes.  Check out this presentation for more info http://www.slideshare.net/garann/using-templates-to-achieve-awesomer-architecture

Comment: I think jquery templates were removed.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of creating the html, you can use jquery functions, ***available in 1.4+***, to make you code much cleaner. Here is an example:

```
$("#content").append($("<div/>", {class : 'row'}).append($("<span/>", {class:'label', text : 'Dining Style'})))
```

The above code will generate:

```
<div class="row"><span class="label">Dining Style</span></div>
```

You still have to loop to create the three children but this is much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

I'm would use a templating system like [iCanHaz.js](http://icanhazjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Append Child
Create Element
or most simply, innerHTML: http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-innerHTML.php